# Displaying SF Symbols as an Image Literal?

Tags: swift, xcode, sf-symbols, image-literals

Xcode will allow me to introduce image literals in code when I start typing `image literal` and use autocomplete:

> [image]

With iOS 13, they released [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/) that can be introduced into the code like so:

```
let image = UIImage(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
```

Is there any way to combine the two and see the SF Symbol as an image literal?

When I try double clicking the image, I only see a selection box for the images provided by my xcassets file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR Xcode does not support combining the two.

---

If you comment the image literal code, you can see that it's actually inserting the following code:

```
static let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: )
```

Attempting to do either of the following does not work:

- `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "trash")`
- `#imageLiteral(systemName: "trash")`

Therefore, I don't think image literals with SF Symbols are supported as of Xcode 11.3.1.